# autoconf alternative to AC_TRY_EVAL macro?

Tags: macros, autotools, autoconf

I am using the AC_TRY_EVAL macro in a configure.ac. However, http://www.mail-archive.com/autoconf@gnu.org/msg17799.html says that this is discouraged for several reasons.

So, I was wondering if there is an alternative, recommended macro for this?

I don't want to simply call the bash's eval-command as I like the logging performed by AC_TRY_EVAL in config.log. It helps trace down possible issues.

Any suggestions please?

Best,

Shadow

Comment: Did you end up finding an alternative?

Comment: TBH, I do not remember :/